# CRC implementation for ethernet

Tags: ethernet, crc

With an example for data with a hexadecimal value of `0xda` and a polynomial `0x07`, I would find the CRC as follows (using the methodology from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_redundancy_check))

`0xda = 11011010`

```
11011010|00000000
111
00111010|00000000
  111
00000010|00000000
      11 1
00000001|10000000
       1 11
00000000|01000000
```

But the answer should be `0x08` according to [this calculator](http://crccalc.com/?crc=da&method=crc8&datatype=hex).

I need the answer to be correct for the IEEE standard Ethernet. I've found that some sources pad the data and some [don't](https://www.lammertbies.nl/comm/info/crc-calculation.html). IEEE seem to suggest padding is required if the data is less than the CRC width.

Note: I know that the CRC is not strictly the remainder of the data divided by the polynomial either.

```
0xda = 11011010 = 218
0x07 = 00000111 = 7
218/7 = 31 r 1
```

As you can see below, the IEEE outlines a lot more steps than suggested on Wikipedia. How can I be certain that the CRC calculators online give the correct values for Ethernet?

[image: Ethernet crc standard]

For my attempt at following the standard (with the 8 bit CRC example)
a.) First 8 bits of the frame are complemented

```
11011010 -> 00100101
```

c.) Multiply by x^8 is equivalent to shifting by 8 bits (padded with zeros)

```
00100101 -> 00100101 00000000 = 18688
```

d.) Divide by `G(x)` and get remainder  `R(x)`

```
18688/7 = 2669 r 5
```

Update: I have since got an 8 bit vhdl implementation using a 256 entry lookup table working. Or at least it gives the same results as the calculator online.

Comment: Is the CRC seeded ?

Answer (score 3):

Your misunderstanding happens right at the beginning. The polynomial given as 0x7 (when given in normal notation) is at least a 4 bit CRC, the calculator you reference calculates an 8 bit CRC.

In the normal notation, the leading bit of the polynomial is 1 and omitted. So for an 8 bit CRC (if we want to check the calculator) the actual polynomial is not just `111` but 9 bit long: `10000011 1` because the leading 9th bit is omitted in that notation.

If I do the calculation with that:

```
11011010 00000000
10000011 1
-----------------
01011001 10000000
 1000001 11
-----------------
00011000 01000000
   10000 0111
-----------------
00001000 00110000
    1000 00111
-----------------
00000000 00001000
```

Voilá the result from the calculator pops out 0x08.

When dealing with CRCs they are always talking about polynomial division and not normal division with remainder.

I suggest you read up on the [mathematics behind that](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematics_of_cyclic_redundancy_checks) and as you are interested in a VHDL implementation I guess that [the computations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computation_of_cyclic_redundancy_checks) are also quite useful.

The step `a)` corresponds to an init value in the calculator of all `FF` in case someone wonders. With that step added the result looks like this:

```
00100101 00000000
  100000 111
-----------------
00000101 11100000
     100 000111
-----------------
00000001 11111100
       1 00000111
-----------------
00000000 11111011
```

So the result is 0xFB. The calculator linked in the OP doesn't provide that value (not a standard polynomial it seems). [This calculator](http://www.sunshine2k.de/coding/javascript/crc/crc_js.html) allows to define a CRC yourself.
And if I use the CRC-8 polynomial and an initial value of 0xFF, the result is the following:

[image: CRC8 calculation]

So the same as my hand calculation.